# Consolidate 2 different RESX files - Windows ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, resx

We have several RESX files from several different projects in the company that we need to consolidate into 1 common.RESX to share among them all. There is some overlap between the files, they are not the same, but there are common nodes.

Is there a tool which can take 2 different RESX files and create 1 new combines one which doesn't double up common elements?

Comment: Are the Resx files named the same?  You have more than element name collision to worry about.  All the applications that use the common RESX have to be adapted to use the common file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is such a tool, but it is pretty easy to write.

Here's a quick example:

```
static XDocument MergeResxFiles(string[] files)
{
    var allResources =
        from f in files
        let doc = XDocument.Load(f)
        from e in doc.Root.Elements("data")
        select Resource.Parse(e, f);

    var elements = new List<XElement>();
    foreach (var g in allResources.GroupBy(r => r.Name))
    {
        elements.AddRange(MergeResources(g.Key, g));
    }
    var output = new XDocument(new XElement("root", elements));
    return output;
}

private static IEnumerable<XElement> MergeResources(string name, IEnumerable<Resource> resources)
{
    var grouped = resources.GroupBy(r => r.Value).ToList();
    if (grouped.Count == 1)
    {
        yield return grouped[0].First().Xml;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Duplicate entries for {name}");
        foreach (var g in grouped)
        {
            var comments = g.Select(r => new XComment($"Source: {r.FileName}"));
            yield return new XElement(
                "data",
                comments,
                new XAttribute("name", name),
                new XElement("value", g.Key));
        }
    }
}

class Resource
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Value { get; }
    public string FileName { get; }
    public XElement Xml { get; }

    public Resource(string name, string value, string fileName, XElement xml)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
        FileName = fileName;
        Xml = xml;
    }

    public static Resource Parse(XElement element, string fileName)
    {
        string name = element.Attribute("name").Value;
        string value = element.Element("value").Value;
        return new Resource(name, value, fileName, element);
    }
}
```

This will generate a new resx document with the resources from the specified files, with the following behavior:

- if a resource exists in several resx files:

  - if the value is the same in all files, output a single resource
  - else, output all different resources with this name, with comments indicating which files they came from to help resolve conflicts.
- else, output the single resource

The code prints the names of duplicate resources to the console to identify them easily.

For instance, if you have 2 resx files with the following resources:

- `Test`, present in both files with the same value
- `Foo`, present in both files with different values
- `Bar`, present only in the first file
- `Baz`, present only in the second file

Then the output looks like this:

```xml
<root>
  <data name="Test" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>The value for Test</value>
  </data>
  <data name="Foo">
    <!--Source: D:\tmp\resx\resources1.resx-->
    <value>The value for Foo</value>
  </data>
  <data name="Foo">
    <!--Source: D:\tmp\resx\resources2.resx-->
    <value>Other value for Foo</value>
  </data>
  <data name="Bar" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>The value for Bar</value>
  </data>
  <data name="Baz" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>The value for Baz</value>
  </data>
</root>
```

(note: this code wasn't thoroughly tested, and might need some fixes and adjustments)

Answer (score 1):

Using Thomas's code here's a simple Console app which will combine the 2 resources files into 1 xml document. Note there is no error handling, just a quick tool.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace MergeResx
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var folder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory),"resx");
        var x = MergeResxFiles(new [] { Path.Combine(folder,args[0]), Path.Combine(folder, args[1])});
        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(folder, "merged.xml"), x.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("--done--");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static XDocument MergeResxFiles(string[] files)
    {
        var allResources =
            from f in files
            let doc = XDocument.Load(f)
            from e in doc.Root.Elements("data")
            select Resource.Parse(e, f);

        var elements = new List<XElement>();
        var enumerable = allResources.GroupBy(r => r.Name).OrderBy(x=>x.Key).ToList();
        foreach (var g in enumerable)
        {
            elements.AddRange(MergeResources(g.Key, g));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Terms: " + enumerable.Count());
        var output = new XDocument(new XElement("root", elements));
        return output;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<XElement> MergeResources(string name, IEnumerable<Resource> resources)
    {
        var grouped = resources.GroupBy(r => r.Value).ToList();
        if (grouped.Count == 1)
        {
            yield return grouped[0].First().Xml;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Duplicate entries for {name}");
            foreach (var g in grouped)
            {
                var comments = g.Select(r => new XComment($"Source: {r.FileName}"));
                yield return new XElement(
                    "data",
                    comments,
                    new XAttribute("name", name),
                    new XElement("value", g.Key));
            }
        }
    }

    class Resource
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public string Value { get; }
        public string Comment { get; }
        public string FileName { get; }
        public XElement Xml { get; }

        public Resource(string name, string value, string fileName,string comment, XElement xml)
        {
            Name = name;
            Value = value;
            Comment = comment;
            FileName = fileName;
            Xml = xml;
        }

        public static Resource Parse(XElement element, string fileName)
        {
            string name = element.Attribute("name").Value;
            string value = element.Element("value").Value;
            string comment = element.Element("comment")?.Value;
            return new Resource(name, value, fileName, comment, element);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem right now. Thanks to previous replies. I modified the represented code (added paralellism and reduced the number of `new` operators) to increase the processing speed. 
Plus, now you can set any number of files and folders in the parameters of the command line (folders will be searched for ".resx" files), or not specify sources at all (files ".resx" will be searched in the current directory). You can also specify the name of the result file (the default is "Resources.resx" in the current directory) and the key "-noduplicates" (if you specify this key, duplicates will not be inserted, except the first one encountered)

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace MergeResX
{
    static class MergeResX
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var settings = args
                .Select(arg => arg[0] == '-' ? ("keys", arg.TrimStart('-')) : Directory.Exists(arg) ? ("directories", arg) : File.Exists(arg) ? ("sources", arg) : ("targets", arg))
                .Concat(new (string, string)[] { ("keys", null), ("directories", null), ("sources", null), ("targets", null), })
                .GroupBy(item => item.Item1)
                .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Select(item => item.Item2).Where(item => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item)))
                ;

            var files = settings["directories"].Any() || settings["sources"].Any()
                ? settings["directories"]
                .AsParallel()
                .Select(directory => new DirectoryInfo(directory))
                .SelectMany(directory => directory.EnumerateFiles("*.resx", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                .Concat(settings["sources"].AsParallel().Select(source => new FileInfo(source)))
                : (new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())).EnumerateFiles()
                ;

            var resources = files
                .AsParallel()
                .Where(file => file.Length > 0)
                .Select(file => XDocument.Load(file.FullName))
                .SelectMany(document => document.Root.Elements("data"))
                .GroupBy(element => element.Attribute("name")?.Value)
                .SelectMany(group => group
                                    .GroupBy(item => item.Attribute("value")?.Value)
                                    .SelectMany(grouped => !grouped.Skip(1).Any() || settings["keys"].Contains("noduplicates", StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                                                            ? grouped.Take(1)
                                                            : grouped.Select(item => item.WithComment("NAME DUPLICATED IN FEW RESX FILES DURING MERGE! LOOK AROUND THIS ELEMENT! BE CAREFULLY!"))))
                ;

            new XDocument(new XElement("root", resources)).Save(settings["targets"].FirstOrDefault() ?? "Resources.resx");
        }

        static XElement WithComment(this XElement element, string comment)
        {
            element.AddFirst(new XComment(comment));
            return element;
        }
    }
}
```